# systemd: poweroff.target and reboot.target

Tags: linux, systemd

In a nutshell, why `systemctl list-units` doesn't list `poweroff.target` or `reboot.target` and `systemctl list-unit-files` does? The .target files are in `/lib/systemd/system` folder; `systemctl cat poweroff.target` and `systemctl cat reboot.target` shows the unit content. `systemd.special(7)` describes them and states those are special units. So, what is the difference, let's say, between `poweroff.target` and `multi-user.target` that one shows up in list-units command and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, because they’re inactive and/or disabled.

`systemctl list-units` only lists active units by default. When the system is running, the `poweroff` and `reboot` targets aren’t active, so they’re not listed. You can add `-a` to see all enabled units, which will add some special targets (but not necessarily all; on my system, `poweroff` is disabled).

`systemctl list-unit-files` lists all installed units in the file system, regardless of their status. This means it lists disabled units too (but not generated units).

(Both commands describe this briefly in the footers they output.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had tried `systemctl list-units -a` and poweroff.target and reboot.target didn't show up either. So, the reason is they are disabled, huh? That means there are unit files for them but they were not "installed" using `systemctl enable <unit>`, right? Thanks

Comment: `list-unit-files` will show their status, but yes, if they’re not listed with `list-units -a`, they’re not enabled.